# echo to stderr and tee to log file?

Tags: bash

In bash script,

> echo "error" 1>&2 | tee -a log

will print stderr in screen but no log to file, how to do these at same time?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To echo the text to both the log file and stderr, *but not stdout*, try this:

```
echo "error" | tee -a log 1>&2
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what the OP wanted to do, but this is by far the best solution for my own case. I think the problem is that it's easy to think the redirection should be applied to the `echo`, but doing it to the `tee` command works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

```
echo "error" 1>&2 | tee -a log
```

With the first part `1>&2`, what you are saying is: **"Redirect stdout to stderr"**. So the *echoed* output `"error"` goes to stderr.

Pipe (`|`) only reads from `stdout`, not `stderr`. So `tee` doesn't get any `stdin` at all from the pipe. Hence, it appends nothing to the log file.

Comment: +1. Very fine answer, except for a solution: it might be worthwile to mention `2>&1` as correct for this purpose.

Comment: yes, ic. But how to echo to stderr and write err log to file?

Comment: @timy If you *redirect* stderr to stdout then you can do that: `echo "error" 2>&1 | tee -a log`. Now both stderr will also go to stdout and you can see both on the screen and will also append to the log.

Comment: @KingsIndian 2>&1 will output nothing to stderr, which is I want to do here.

Comment: @timy Unless some acutal error occurs "echo"ed output will only go `stdout`. You are right that `2>&1` will write nothing to stderr. But since stdout & stderr both go to console,  you don't really need to worry about that.

Answer (score 7):

To view both stdout and stderr on the console and send both streams to a log, redirect stderr to stdout as shown below:

```
progam.sh 2>&1 | tee -a log
```

Answer (score 0):

But default only stdout is passed along in pipes, so that in

```
$ echo "error" | tee
```

`tee` only sees the stout from the `echo`, not the stderr. stderr will still be displayed in the terminal.